# How to use a variable for a task command in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have numerous tasks in my Visual studio workspace, and I do not want to repeat the program full path in all the tasks.

I read the documentation at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference, I don't need input variable, command variable and environment variable seams to fit to my need, but it does not work.

In my project.code-workspace file:

```
"tasks": {

    "options": {
        "env": { "longComandPath": "c:/This/is/a/long/command/that/points/to/the/program.exe" }
    },

    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "LibFM_Lite-Regen",
            "type": "shell",
            "group": "build",
            "command": "${env:longComandPath}",
            "args": [ "-verbose" ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "X",
            }
        }
        ...
    ]
}
```

The result is:

```
> Executing task in folder X:      -verbose

-verbose is not recognized as an applet command
```

So "${env:longComandPath}" is evaluated as an empty string

I use Visual Studio Code 1.6.3.

Answer (score 0):

Place your options object outside the tasks object:

```
"options": {
   "env": { "longComandPath": "c:/This/is/a/long/command/that/points/to/the/program.exe" }
},
tasks:{
  "command": "${env:longComandPath}",
}
```

Then reference it inside the tasks object.

Comment: I just updated my post sample because it was wrong: the options is outside of the tasks array, but inside of the tasks object. As tasks are defined in a workspace, I have to set the tasks array in the tasks object. If options are outside of the tasks object, then VS code tell it is not supported.

Comment: And if options are inside tasks object and ouside task array, it is supported by VS code (doeos not appear grayed out) but it does not seam to be taken into account.